# ag-grid React run on every render

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I want to re-run

```js
            headerComponentFramework: (params) => {
                console.log('xxx');
            },
```

every single time the data value changes

```js
      <AgGridReact
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                rowData={data}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh a header, you can use the Grid API method `refreshHeader`.

To refresh a header when the data changes, you can listen to the following Grid Events: `onCellValueChanged`, `onRowDataChanged` and `onRowDataUpdated`.

See this implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jTJPwiKiOGcCMxGk?open=index.jsx).

```
  const rowDataChanged = (params) => {
    console.log('rowDataChanged');
    params.api.refreshHeader();
  };

  const rowDataUpdated = (params) => {
    console.log('rowDataUpdated');
    params.api.refreshHeader();
  };

  const cellValueChanged = (params) => {
    console.log('cellValueChanged');
    params.api.refreshHeader();
  };
```